# TypeScript object literal type assertion with generics

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have a TypeScript class like so:

```
class Foo<Props extends {}> {
    public readonly props: Props;
    public readonly otherStuff: string[];

    constructor(properties: Props | string[], otherStuff?: string[]) {
      if (properties instanceof Array) {
        this.otherStuff = properties;
        this.props = {} as Props;
      } else {
        this.props = properties;
        this.otherStuff = otherStuff || [];
      }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this results in a [no-object-literal-type-assertion](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-object-literal-type-assertion/) rule failure in tslint (on the `this.props = {} as Props` line). If I remove the `as Props` part I get an error that `{}` isn't assignable to type `Props`.

How would you go about setting this up without disabling that `tslint` rule?

For reference, here's an expected usage:

```
type X = { foo: string; }

const foo = new Foo<X>({ foo: 'bar' });
const foo2 = new Foo(['']);
```

Comment: I'm a little rusty on TypeScript at the moment, but would `this.props = <Props>{};` work?

Comment: @bkbooth yes, it can be written that way but it then violates https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-angle-bracket-type-assertion/ ;)

Comment: Ok, thought that might have been a little too obvious. I've only used the angle brackets type assertions when I was last using TypeScript regularly.

Comment: Do you actually need that? Why not give props a default value so you don't have this checking

Comment: @Sugendran It's implementing a constructor overload approach, where the `props` are optional.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think TSLint is actually saving you here.  Let's say the warning wasn't there, and you did this:

```
interface X { someProperty: number };
var foo = new Foo<X>(['']);
var bar: number = foo.props.someProperty;
```

Even though `someProperty` isn't optional, it would be returning `undefined` - the fact is `{}` is not assignable to a variable of type`X` and tslint is rightly stopping you in your tracks.

I'd reconsider your approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve here.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do:

`public props: Props | {}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
 this.props = new Props();
```

Comment: This is making the assumption that `Props` is a constructable type, which based on the generic restriction it is not, this is a valid `Props` object: `{ foo: 'bar' }`